# How to setup Cucumber, Guard & Spork with Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber, spork, guard

I'm trying to setup cucumber, rspec, guard and spork.  I've got rspec working fine but cucumber crashes with the trace below.

I've try setting this up several times, 
rails g cucumber:install --spork
spork cucumber --boostrap
etc... with no luck.

Gems:
rails (3.1.3)
guard (0.10.0)
guard-bundler (0.1.3)
guard-cucumber (0.7.4, 0.7.3)
guard-rails (0.0.3)
guard-rspec (0.6.0, 0.5.2)
guard-spork (0.5.1, 0.5.0)
cucumber (1.1.4)
cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
spork (0.9.0)

```
Running all features
Using the default profile...
Running tests with args ["--color", "--format", "pretty", "--require", "/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/guard-cucumber-0.7.4/lib/guard/cucumber/notification_formatter.rb", "--format", "Guard::Cucumber::NotificationFormatter", "--out", "/dev/null", "--require", "features", "features", "--format", "pretty", "--strict", "--tags", "~@wip", "features", "--no-profile"]...
Disabling profiles...
Exception encountered: #<RuntimeError: All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT)>
backtrace:
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:198:in `arrange_formats'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:26:in `parse!'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:55:in `configuration'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `run_drb_client'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:24:in `run_tests'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@alphascore/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1558:in `perform_without_block'
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1518:in `perform'
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1592:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `loop'
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in `block in main_loop'
Done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this, after playing around with flags passed to cucumber via my guardfile I was able to resolve conflicting flags and not overriding my cucumber.yml flags.

**Working Guardfile**

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb" do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```

**cucumber.yml**

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: --drb <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --drb --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: --drb <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

**Conflicting Guardfile**

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--drb --color --format pretty" do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```